# Get property by string name (PHP)

Tags: php, string, properties

If I have the following class property `$classProperty = "Initial value"`, how can I access it with another property, `$propertyName = "classProperty"`? I want to do something like `${$propertyName} = "Modified value"` and get `echo $classProperty` to output: `"Modified value"`.

Comment: By property you mean HTML classes?

Comment: Uhmm didn't get your question at all. What I understood I think you meant to refer to access a class instance attribute ? Please be more specific

Comment: variable variables... BAD idea... You COULD use references. `$foo = &$bar; $bar = 'baz'; echo $foo` would output `baz`...

Comment: I'm talking about PHP class properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting class properties into an array

```
private $_arProp = array();
```

Then, use keys to identify the property

```
$_arProp[ 'key' ] = 'Property Value';
```

This should help I think.

Comment: I can use property_exists() to check if a property exists, I would like to set it if it exists but I don't know how to get access to it once it's been confirmed that it exists. The thing is that my class has a lot of properties and so I would like to be able to set them like SetProperty($theProperty, $theValue). And the SetProperty method would check if the property exists and if so give it the value.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a static property, you can probably do `ClassName::$$propertyName`.

For properties of an instance, do `$instance->$propertyName`